# Assign the same sequence elements a number of consecutive repetitions

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I am working with a SQL Server table that looks like this:

| diff | nom | rec_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -7 | abc | 9 |
| -6 | abc | 9 |
| -5 | abc | 7 |
| -4 | abc | 6 |
| -3 | abc | 6 |
| -2 | abc | 6 |
| -1 | abc | 13 |
| -7 | fav | 7 |
| -6 | fav | 9 |
| -5 | fav | 9 |
| -4 | fav | 13 |
| -3 | fav | 7 |
| -2 | fav | 7 |
| -1 | fav | 7 |

Real table is so much larger, this is the sample.

I need to assign to each `rec_num` of the table the number of their consecutive repetitions.  For example, there is a sequence `5 5 4 4 4 3 5 5 5 5 1`, then the result of the work should be `2 2 3 3 3 1 4 4 4 4 1`. I need exactly the number of repetitions **in a row**, not the total number of repeats.

Using the combination of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
with cte as (
  select diff, nom, rec_num,
  row_number() over (partition by nom order by nom, diff desc) rn1,
  row_number() over (partition by nom, rec_num order by nom, diff desc) rn2
  from t)
  
 select diff, nom, rec_num,
   row_number() over (partition by nom, rn1 - rn2 order by nom, diff desc) as con_repeats
from cte
```

I got the following table

| diff | nom | rec_num | con_repeats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | abc | 13 | 1 |
| -2 | abc | 6 | 1 |
| -3 | abc | 6 | 2 |
| -4 | abc | 6 | 3 |
| -5 | abc | 7 | 1 |
| -6 | abc | 9 | 1 |
| -7 | abc | 9 | 2 |
| -1 | fav | 7 | 1 |
| -2 | fav | 7 | 2 |
| -3 | fav | 7 | 3 |
| -4 | fav | 13 | 1 |
| -5 | fav | 9 | 1 |
| -6 | fav | 9 | 2 |
| -7 | fav | 7 | 1 |

But I need the table look like this:

| diff | nom | rec_num | con_repeats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | abc | 13 | 1 |
| -2 | abc | 6 | 3 |
| -3 | abc | 6 | 3 |
| -4 | abc | 6 | 3 |
| -5 | abc | 7 | 1 |
| -6 | abc | 9 | 2 |
| -7 | abc | 9 | 2 |
| -1 | fav | 7 | 3 |
| -2 | fav | 7 | 3 |
| -3 | fav | 7 | 3 |
| -4 | fav | 13 | 1 |
| -5 | fav | 9 | 2 |
| -6 | fav | 9 | 2 |
| -7 | fav | 7 | 1 |

How can I do this?

Comment: can you please share your current query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this simply with `group by`

```
with x as (
    select nom, rec_num, Count(*) n
    from t
    group by nom,rec_num
)
update t set t.con_repeats=x.n
from x
join t on t.nom=x.nom and t.rec_num=x.rec_num
```

see [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/071649/4)

**Edit**

After clarification of the problem, a different solution is required, this uses `window functions` to identify the islands of repeating values and `updatable CTE` to apply the `max count` of each island group to the source table:

```
with groups as (
    select t.*,
        Dense_Rank() over (partition by nom order by (rn - rn2), rec_num) as grp,
        Row_Number() over (partition by nom, (rn - rn2), rec_num order by diff) as c
    from(
        select t.*, row_number() over (partition by nom order by diff) as rn, Row_Number() over (partition by nom, rec_num order by diff) as rn2
        from t
    )t
),
cnt as (
    select *, Max(c) over (partition by nom,grp) maxc
    from groups
)
update cnt set con_repeats=maxc;

select * from t;
```

See this [New fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ccb1cb/2)

Comment: Can you tell me what the performance of the code is? Will it run faster than the `row_number` combination?

Comment: With index on num & rec_num it will be much faster - other than that, your row number does not work, so it's a non-starter?!

Comment: See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/474f1c/1). Your code does not work properly, there is an error with `nom='fav'` and `diff = -1, -2, -3 and -7`

Comment: @tsr There's no error in the fiddle, the code runs. The values also looks correct, at least with my understanding of your desired output - presumably you mean the value is wrong?   Row -1 for 'fav' has a value of 4, the same as the other 3 rows, there are 4 "sevens"; how is this wrong?

Comment: I mean, if there is a sequence, for example `5 5 4 4 4 3 5 5 5 5 1`, then the result of the work should be `2 2 3 3 3 1 4 4 4 4 1`. I need exactly the number of repetitions **in a row**, not the total number of repeats

Comment: @tsr - Sorry don't follow you - there is no "sequence" involved - the query updates the table and populates the con_repeats column with the correct `count` of how many times that value appears for the same `nom` value. That's what your example output appears to show - if that's not right I think you haven't clearly demonstrated the question.

Comment: So if I understand what you're saying, -7 should be 1 and -3/-2/-1 should be 3? If that's the case the sample data in your Fiddle above is what you should have put in your question initially.

Comment: my bad, you are right in the last comment

Comment: no prob. Your sample data literally showed your results to be the count of the number of occurences of each value; that's *very different* to what you're now asking, which becomes a more complex gaps-and-islands problem and needs a totally different approach.

Comment: @tsr, check out the edit to my answer above, does this now operate as you intend?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I added `diff = -8` and for `nom = fav` and `diff = -7 / -8` and your output is 5, but should be 2. See [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ccb1cb/1)

Comment: Can you update the fiddle and I'll take another look

Comment: @tsr how about 3rd time lucky? Have amended above and updated the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ccb1cb/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Please see if this helps.

SELECT t1.*, repeats FROM tbl t1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT repeats, nom, rec_num FROM (
        (SELECT COUNT(*) repeats, nom, rec_num FROM tbl GROUP BY nom, rec_num))t
     ) t2
ON t2.nom = t1.nom and t2.rec_num = t1.rec_num
ORDER BY nom, diff DESC
```

Comment: See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5e829/1). There is an error with `nom='fav'` and `diff = -1, -2, -3 and -7`